# the parameter 'token_pattern' will not be used since 'tokenizer' is not none'

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am trying to remove punctuation and spaces (which includes newlines) and filter for tokens consisting of alphabetic
characters only, and return the token text.
I first define the function

```
  return [t.text for t in nlp(doc) if \
          not t.is_punct and \
          not t.is_space and \
          t.is_alpha]
```

And then i vectorize

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=spacy_tokenizer)
train_feature_vects = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
```

The terminal gets stuck, and says the parameter 'token_pattern' will not be used since 'tokenizer' is not none'.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For `TfidfVectorizer`, `CountVectorizer`, etc. in *scikit-learn*, to define your own `tokenizer`, you also need to set `token_pattern` to `None`:

```py
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=spacy_tokenizer, token_pattern=None)
```

*scikit-learn* will use the `token_pattern` for tokenisation, if not specified, it will use the default value `r”(?u)\b\w\w+\b”`. this will override the `tokenizer` you define. So you need to set `token_pattern` to `None`, and *scikit-learn* will use the function you pass to `tokenizer` for the tokenization step.